# How can I create a full-width container for a Sigma.js graph?

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

I'm trying to create a graph using Sigma.js that fills the entire space of the page. Right now the default layout is a square:

[image: Sigma.js default layout]

I've read through the docs and I think I have to create a [custom renderer](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki/Renderers#building-a-custom-renderer). I've looked at the project's [existing renderer for Canvas](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/src/renderers/sigma.renderers.canvas.js) but I'm not sure where I would specify the page's full width and height.

Any tips or help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I had to set `scalingMode` to `'outside'`:

https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki/Settings#rescale-settings

Comment: The documentation's location has changed, which is why it's valuable to include the solution in the answer and not just a link to it.